# SQL query in C# (System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException: 'Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression)

Tags: c#, sql, ms-access

```
OleDbCommand commandtwo = new OleDbCommand("SELECT * from tblShowings WHERE ShowFilmID = " + filmID.Text + " AND Showdate = " + date.Text + " AND Showtime = " + time.Text + "", con);
```

What is wrong with my SQL query? I keep getting this error:

> System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException: 'Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression 'ShowFilmID = 1111 AND Showdate = 67/87/9999 AND Showtime = 10:00'

Comment: Parametrized query!

Comment: Well clearly your strings in the query need quotes around them to be valid SQL. But as @LukaszSzozda says, use parameters instead of string concatenation and you will solve a lot of other problems at the same time.

Comment: What date is this? _67/87/9999_

Comment: @Steve: It's an invalid one.

Comment: @steve i was just testing a random date to test if the sql query would work

Comment: Could you tell us what are the datetypes for the columns _ShowFilmID, ShowDate and ShowTime_ in the table tblShowings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current code is vulnerable to Sql Injections. You should be using parameterized query to avoid sql injections and handling of value types correctly.

The error in your code is because you are missing `'` single quotes for string value types.

```
"ShowFilmID = '" + date.Text + "'" + ...
```

Here's an example how you should be using parameterized query:

```
OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(
  "SELECT * from tblShowings WHERE ShowFilmID = ? AND Showdate = ? AND Showtime = ?", con);
OleDbParameterCollection paramCollection = command.Parameters;
OleDbParameter myParm = paramCollection.Add(
        new OleDbParameter("ShowFilmID", filmID.Text),
        new OleDbParameter("Showdate", date.Text),
        new OleDbParameter("Showtime", time.Text));
```

Comment: What makes you think that ShowFilmID is a string field and requires quotes around the values to compare?

Comment: Thanks! @Steve fixed it. Used date field for illustration.

Answer (score 0):

Just a point to ponder here from a security standpoint. You need to ensure your data input/output is validated/sanitized to avoid exploit. The ideal process is stored procedure and parameterized values. If that is not possible, ensure that you have encoded your values so to avoid SQL Injection. Just my 2 cents worth.